# django leaflet - adding/removing controls on HTML page button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, leaflet

I am currently using django-leaflet and leaflet-draw controls. I want to make the draw controls available (add to map) on a certain event such as a toggle button.

I currently have a simple jQuery skeleton:

```
$("#mode").on("click", function() {

    if(document.getElementById('mode').checked) {
        $("#save").removeClass("hidden");
        alert("Edit Mode");
        //event where I want to add controls to map
        //map.addControl(drawControl);

       } else {
        $("#save").addClass("hidden");
        alert("View Mode");
        //event where I want to remove controls from map
        //map.removeControl(drawControl);
    }
});
```

I have my map.js external from the html file and I call this in my template with only this line (as instructed in django-leaflet):

```
{% leaflet_map "mapdiv" callback="leafletinit" %}
```

*Note: I also tried to include the drawControl variable available on the same page but I don't think I'm doing it correctly... My map.js is loading correctly as it does load the map and the controls on a straight forward no event view*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without django?

Simply adding:

```
<Div id = 'map'> </ div>

Var map = L.map ( 'map')
```

I've never set the template variable in Django when it came to Leaflet. I keep the common "leaflet javascript" way for the best!

Especially when it comes to add some addons / plugins / extensions to Leaflet.

If you prefer Django, it would be good if you could publish your whole template (html)!